# Joda DateTimeFormat without - separator?

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to make a joda LocalDate in the format of yyyyMMdd, but every time I parse it to create the object, it inserts hyphens like yyyy-MM-dd for no apparent reason.

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd");
LocalDate d = format.parseLocalDate("20150101");
```

Is there a way to get this to end up looking like 20150101 or will it forever be 2015-01-01?

Comment: Are you using `formatter` to `print` the date also?

Comment: @vikingsteve I am not printing it, it just does this automatically when checking test cases.

Comment: Ok, well when you compare it against a string in your test case, you need to know, or specify your own, format.

Comment: :| thanks haha I don't know why I didn't think about that

Answer (score 1):

Solution is not to use the `toString()`-method:

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd");
LocalDate d = format.parseLocalDate("20150101");
System.out.println(format.print(d)); // 20150101
System.out.println(d); // using toString(): 2015-01-01
```

Quite simple, isn't it? For me, the form using hyphens is more readable, so this is a natural choice for the standard output of the method `toString()`.

By the way: Both variants are valid ISO-8601-strings. The form without hyphens is called BASIC DATE while the form with hyphens is called EXTENDED DATE.

Comment: Thank you for the exact name of the formats. However, I am not using toString. The problem only arises with test cases when it will say something like "2015-01-01 not equal to 20150101", so I assumed it was performing some default formatting when checking test cases.

Comment: @fiveandten Can you please show your test cases (with code) where you observe the deviation?